# ng2-date-time-picker other control events stop firing after date selection

Tags: javascript, forms, visual-studio, angular, datepicker

I am using the template created via the "dotnet new angular" command.

I have a form which is working fine in all respects, until I add the ng2-date-time-picker control. The control works fine in terms of passing the selected values to a variable on the component when I set it up as explained here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-date-time-picker.

```
<input [ngModel]="momentValue | date: 'short'" [dateTimePicker]="momentValue" (dateTimePickerChange)="setMoment($event)" readonly />
```

However, after that happens:

-- The submit button no longer triggers the (submit) method bound to the form.

-- checkboxes on the form stop firing a (change) event.

It is as if the datepicker control does not return event handling to the main form.

I like this control, but I obviously can't use it if other controls on my form (including the submit button) become nonresponsive. I do note, however, that (click) events continue to fire.

Has anyone else had this problem? Any ideas?

Comment: [File an issue](https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker/issues) with the ng2-date-timepicker authors.

Comment: use primeng calendar

Comment: I have logged the issue here: https://github.com/DanielYKPan/date-time-picker/issues/62

Comment: The author's response was that the package has been deprecated, and the new package only supports angular 4.*